# nginx multiple paths (too many)

Tags: nginx, configuration, optimization, path

i got this working nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/mydomain/wordpress;

  index index.html index.php;

  location /customer1 {
    alias /var/www/mydomain/customers/custumer1;
  }

  location /customer2 {
    alias /var/www/mydomain/customers/custumer2;
  }
...
  location /customerN {
    alias /var/www/mydomain/customers/custumerN;
  }
```

where customer1...customerN are nicknames.

the problem is that custmers are growing fast.  so, is there a way to make this config more efficient? is there a way to create arrays maybe?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `location` block:

```
location ~ ^/customer(?<customerid>[0-9])$ {
    alias /var/www/mydomain/customers/customer$customerid;
}
```

Here we use a regular expression to capture the customer number into `$customerid` variable and then use the variable at `alias` statement.

Regular expressions are a very powerful method of matching different kind of text strings, so you can easily adapt this to cover for longer numbers etc.

Comment: but "custumer1" is a generic name.  that was jus an example.  real names are not based on IDs.

Comment: Then just modify the regex accordingly.

Comment: i've been thinking about it. but how can i achieve this when customer names are like nicknames, it could be anything!

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks... strange.
First of all, alias in nginx, is not same as Alias in apache.
http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias
You should use root instead, if I undestand you right
http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

If customer URI-s are like
http://example.com/random_customer_name

Then you should something like that:

```
location / {
    root /var/www/mydomain/customers;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
}

location @php {
    root /var/www/mydomain/wordpress;
    # I think you need some proxying to apache or php-pfm here
}
```

But it have some obvious issues, like user with names wp-login, wp-admin and so on. So it is better to have URI like http://example.com/users/random_customer_name
And config will be as simple as that:

```
location /users {
    root /var/www/mydomain/customers;
}
```

Comment: based on your coments, you think it would be better to work with subdomains.  like: htttp://customername.example.com ?

Comment: That would be safer, but you will have to either create DNS-records and virtualhosts dynamically, or use wildcard subdomains.